# Automatic CSS simplifier tool?

Tags: css, less

I have some complicated and messy CSS, is there some tool which could take this very messy CSS and simplify it?

I know that people often go the other way, they make CSS using a more concise stylesheet language such as http://lesscss.org/ and produce the CSS from this. However my situation is that I have a lot of ugly messy CSS and I want to go the other way.

Comment: Can you please explain why this is not constructive?

Comment: i bet people who closed this question aren't even front end devs

Comment: its closed anyway... so doesn't matter

Comment: CSSBurner (http://www.cssburner.com) can do this - it also locates redundant/repeat selectors and rules and all other types of CSS that can be removed or reduced.

Comment: https://www.codebeautifier.com/ is the first i found that recombines selectors.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob Don't trust a tool that claims to improve CSS if it looks this ugly :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CSS Tidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/) is a good open source optimizer.

Check this [online tool](http://csstidyonline.com/) too. Its pretty cool for quick optimizations.

If you want the entire package, Google provides [closure tools](https://developers.google.com/closure/) which would optimize, and even minify static files for you - from inline styles, javascript, etc

Answer (score 1):

Try an online service like http://cssbeautify.com/. There are plenty of them out there...

Answer (score 0):

You can use online tools:

- http://csslint.net/ for linting
- http://csscomb.com/ for ordering attributes
- http://prefixr.com/ for adding browser prefixes

Browser extentions : 
Dust-Me Selectors for Firefox : http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/

Most tools can be installed directly into your IDE/Text editor via plugins

Answer (score 0):

http://procssor.com/ is nice, has loads of options to suit how you like your css to look.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: tbh the question was looking for a tool to clean up css, which can really only be answered with a link. Without writing a large review for the site I think this answers the question.

Comment: This links appear to bee down, at the moment.